# Can L'Hopital's rule be applied only for a part of a function?

Tags: calculus

For example, in 
$\lim_{x\to 0_+} (x^2 \ln x+bx+c) $
can it be applied only for $x^2\ln x$? (of course not in this form)

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$ as long as $$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$ is finite

Comment: In the worst case, you split your function into terms that don't individually converge, even though the function as a whole converges; in that case you discard that particular attempt and try something else.

Answer (score 3):

If you have $\lim(f(x)+g(x)+\cdots)$, then you can always compute the limit term-wise, i.e.

$$\lim f(x)+\lim g(x)+\cdots$$

as long as all the single limits exist. So in order to apply l'Hospital to only one of the terms, first use this rule to get

$$\lim (x^2\ln(x)+bx+x)=\lim(x^2\ln(x))+\lim(bx+x).$$

Then apply l'Hospital to whatever part you want.

Comment: Let me add that you can do that even if the limits are infinite, as long as the expression that you get in the end does not contain indeterminate forms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} bx+c$ converges (to $c$).

Comment: And if there was ((bx+3)/(cx+4))  for example?

Comment: It converges to $\dfrac 3 4$

Comment: Wanted to say b/x  (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

If $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrowtail\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in((\text{dom}(f))'\cap(\text{dom}(g))')$ and $\exists \lim\limits_af=F, \lim\limits_ag=G$, then $\exists\lim\limits_a(f+g)=F+G$

So you don't need to apply the L'Hospital rule to all of the parts. But both of the limits must exist at the given point, and that point must be a limit point for both of the functions.

And it also applies to a one-sided limit. The difference is that the $a$ point need to be a one-sided limit point instead of a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. To make the problem more general, suppose you have to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to a^+}\bigl(f(x)+g(x)\bigr)
$$
The limit can also be from the left or two-sided; I use $x\to a^+$ just by way of example.

> **General rule.** Splitting a problem into subproblems is a *good thing* to do.

*If* you're able to show that both
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l
\qquad\text{and}
\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=m
$$
exist, *whatever way you do* the separate limits, then you can conclude that
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\bigl(f(x)+g(x)\bigr)=l+m
$$
Easy rules apply when one or both limits are infinity, with the exception for the “indeterminate” case $\infty-\infty$ (or $-\infty+\infty$, of course).

So here's how you can do the given limit.

1. Set $f(x)=x^2\ln x$ and $g(x)=bx+c$;
2. Compute $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=0$ (for instance with l'Hôpital);
3. Compute $\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)=c$;
4. Conclude that $\lim_{x\to0^+}(x^2\ln x+bx+c)=0+c=c$.

Note: the fact that $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^2\ln x=0$ can be proved in several ways without l'Hôpital is irrelevant.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know, L'hospital rule is used in FRACTIONS that are of *zero by zero*  or *infinity by infinity* form.

And in your question, you have a standard limit : lim(x--->0) x^2 ln(x) =0.

But yes, in general you can always separate functions while calculating limits and use L' hospital's rule for some / all of them.

Comment: $x^2\ln (x)= \ln(x)/(1/x^2)$.

Comment: There's no need to write it like that. It's a standard limit.

Comment: This statement will not help you if you have to find the limit yourself.

Comment: We can always use standard limits while proving statements..

Comment: What? Are you going to prove $\lim_{x\to+0} x^2\ln(x)=0$ by searching the internet?

Comment: What's the need to prove it?! We use standard limits directly. I think there's some misunderstanding (I don't know what).

Comment: The need is to understand *why* $0$ is the limit. You learn almost nothing by googling it. We are fighting about unnecessary details here. So let's just stop.

Comment: @user166465 And what if you need to prove that limit? Will you say that it's a "standard limit"?

Comment: For your information, I didn't google it. I already knew it. And i don't think this conversation is not related to what the user has asked. So, I m not participating in this discussion anymore. Sorry.